# Removing an item from a defalutdict(list) based on its timestamp for a rolling queue

Tags: python

I'm tracking a large sum of objects in a csv file and am trying to figure out how many events have happened in a rolling 5 minute interval (for each of a set of players). I'm using defaultdict to store the event times and then counting the number of events stored to give me my rolling total. Each time it calls a line from the csv it's supposed to check the timestamps in defaultdict for that player and if any of the times are more than 5 minutes old (300 seconds) it removes them from the defaultdict. It seems to be kind of working, but it never goes all the way down to 0 (when it's been more than 5 minutes between any events for a player). Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here:

```
fishrollingmeanqueue = defaultdict(list)
def fishInLastNSeconds(num_seconds,ts,player): #I set num_seconds to 300 elsewhere, ts = timestamp for the event
    curTime = timestampToEpoch(ts)
    fishrollingmeanqueue[player].append(curTime)
    for elt in fishrollingmeanqueue[player]:
        if elt < (curTime - num_seconds):
            fishrollingmeanqueue[player].remove(elt)
    return str(len(fishrollingmeanqueue[player]))
```

Comment: which line is not working?

Comment: That's the weird thing... the code "works" but not the way I'd expect it to... sometimes it removes the items from `fishrollingmeanqueue[player]` but not always (as I would expect it to). For instance when I look at the output I have an event at 9:55am and the output gives me a len of 5... then the next event for that player is at 10:55am (an hour later) but it gives me a len of 3, but it should be 1 since every other event should get removed using my for statement

Comment: can you put `fishrollingmeanqueue = defaultdict(list)` inside function ?

Comment: Don't think so - I belive that ends up resetting the defaultdict every time the function is called - I tried it to see and it does seem to reset it to 1 for every instance

Comment: So you need it as global scope, So just `global fishrollingmeanqueue` inside your funtion as first line.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change how it behaves

Comment: Try something `print` whether all execution enters into `if condition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that you're modifying the list at the same time you are iterating over it. This doesn't work right, as list iterators go by index, and the index of later items will change when an earlier one is removed.

As an example, consider a three-element list, `lst=[a,b,c]`. When you iterate over it with `for elt in lst`, Python will create an iterator, which is initially at index `0`. On the first pass through the loop, `elt` will be a reference to `a`, the object at that index. If, within the loop, you remove `a` with `lst.remove(elt)`, the list will now be `[b,c]`. On the next pass, the iterator will be pointing at index 1, and you'll get `c` as `elt`. The second element of the original list, `b`, will have been skipped.

There are a few ways to fix this. Often the best approach is to create a new list with only the items you want to keep, and then replace the old list with the new one:

```
new_q = [elt for elt in fishrollingmeanqueue[player] if elt >= curTime - num_seconds]
fishrollingmeanqueue[player] = newq
```

Other options are to iterate on a copy of the list, or to iterate in reverse so that the indexes of the values yet to be seen won't change.

Comment: Perfect! That makes a lot of sense (once it's explained). Used your suggestion and it worked great (small note there's a tiny typo line two should read `fishrollingmeanqueue[player] = new_q`